# Symfony : database connection depending on a url var

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Is it possible to change the connection to the database in Symfony 4.1 according to the route?
I have a defined number of user and each one has its own database, all databases have the same schema.

I have found a way to do that :
for example, for the route `http://sub.domain.com/one_user`

Ihave change the config file for doctrine like that : (in php)

```
<?php

/**
*  config/packages/doctrine.php
*/

$user=explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];
require_once 'class_to_find_user_details.php';
$inits=new class_to_find_user_details($user);

$container->setParameter('env(DATABASE_URL)','');
$container->loadFromExtension('doctrine',
    array(
        'dbal'  => array(
            'driver'            => 'pdo_mysql',
            'server_version'    => '5.7',
            'charset'           => 'utf8mb4',
            'default_table_options' => array(
                'charset'       => 'utf8mb4',
                'collate'       => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            ),
            'url'               => 'mysql://'.$inits->dbUser.':'.$inits->dbPass.'@'.$inits->dbHost.':3306/'.$inits->dbName,
        ),
        'orm'   => array(
            'auto_generate_proxy_classes'   =>'%kernel.debug%',
            'naming_strategy'               =>'doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore',
            'auto_mapping'                  => true,
            'mappings'                      => array(
                'App'       => array(
                    'is_bundle'     => false,
                    'type'          => 'annotation',
                    'dir'           => '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity',
                    'prefix'        => 'App\Entity',
                    'alias'         => 'App',
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

All that work fine but the problem is that the configuration is cached and when I call `http://sub.domain.com/second_user` I receive the datas from the first user.

Is there a way to prevent caching of this configuration?
Or, is it possible to define the connection to the database from a controller?

thank you in advance for your help.

mblaettermann, Thank you for your comment. So I tried to define all the connections in the configuration files. As follows:

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
parameters:
env(DATABASE_URL): ''
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     'localhost'
                port:     '3306'
                dbname:   'db'
                user:     'userdb'
                password: 'pw'
                charset:  UTF8
            user1:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     'localhost'
                port:     '3306'
                dbname:   'dbNameUser1'
                user:     'dbUserUser1'
                password: 'dbPassUser1'
                charset:  UTF8
            user2:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     'localhost'
                port:     '3306'
                dbname:   'dbNameUser2'
                user:     'dbUserUser2'
                password: 'dbPassUser2'
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            user1:
                connection: user1
                mappings:
                    user1:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: user1
            user2:
                connection: user2
                mappings:
                    user2:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: user2
```

But I still can not use the repository and the entityManager normally in my controller:
for example :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$listeClients=$em->getRepository(Clients::class)->findAll();
```

give the same results as :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('user1');
$listeClients=$em->getRepository(Clients::class)->findAll();
```

in both cases I get the results of the database 'default'.
I think the problem comes from the call to the repository because if I did:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('user1');
$oneClient=$em->find(Clients::class,1);
```

I get an entry from the database 'user1'

Comment: Show the code for `class_to_find_user_details`

Comment: No not possible since the container config is dumped only once, see DoctrineBunlde how to configure multiple connections: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity managers.html

Comment: thanks mblaettermann, I tried to configure multiple connections,but I still have problems moving from one connection to another - see the edited post

Comment: I find a solution  here : https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/9878